# How to scroll an image clipped from rotating from portrait to landscape mode

Tags: xcode, imageview, scrollview

I built a small demo application by starting with a split-view based template. Then using IB I added a Scroll View to the detail view and then an Image View to the Scroll View. Both the Scroll View and the Image View are the same size as the detail view. Finally I added a png image to the Image View the was the same size as the Image View.

When I run this app, starting in portrait mode, everything is fine. But when I rotate the ipad to landscape, I see only a portion of image in the detail view, starting with the upper left corner and going as far down and to the right as will fit in the view. I would like to be able to scroll other portions of the image into view, but the image does not move when I try to drag it. I've played around with properties of the Scroll View and Image View available in IB, but I have not been able to find a configuration that allows me to scroll the image around in landscape mode. Can someone tell me whether and how I might be able to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix the struts and springs of the main sub-view of your UIScrollView.

Inspect that view in IB, go to the tab beside the outlets tab and there you'll see two boxes - the one with 9 dots and another one below it.

The default is that you'll  see the uppermost left dot selected, select the one in the middle instead.

Then turn on the lines that look like 'I' in the box below it: (upper, left, right). Also click on the horizontal arrow that you'll find there.

Hope this helps, just ask me if you have further questions.

Comment: Hi Thanks. That solved half of the problem. Now, in landscape mode, I can drag the image in any direction. But when I drag the image upward so I can see the bottommost portion, the image scrolls back downward as soon as I take my finger off the screen. When I drag the image up I'd like for it to stay up so I can do things at the bottom of the image. And if I can, I'd like avoid scaling (especially) or resizing the image.

Comment: You have to change the contentSize of our UIScrollView. I'm guessing the contentSize is not large enough for you to view the details in the bottom. Set it to the size of the bounds of your subview which contains the details you want to scroll to.